# Creating model to batch select polygons by attribute and merge them together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, merge, batch

Is there is a way to create a ArcGIS 10 MODEL to:

1. batch select polygons from the same layer by attribute
2. merge these polygons into one
3. repeat this for all polygons shearing the same attributes

example:
To create a geological map with all mapping polygons merged into one big polygon of the same lithology.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for the [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dissolve/00170000005n000000/) tool.